# Intellij IDEA Shortcut - delete all code but comments

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javadoc

Is there any Intellij Shortcut that quickly deletes everything in a source code file except for Java comments?
I skimmed through these https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/keyboard-shortcuts-you-cannot-miss.html but seems I did not found anything.

Comment: What are you trying to create? the javadoc? if so, is this what you're looking for? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/generating-javadoc-reference-for-a-project.html

Comment: I'm learning Java and trying to re-create a program from scratch with only the comments and pseudo-code showing up.

Comment: I don't  think that there is such a shortcut in any ide since not a lot of people actually want to delete the comments.
However, what you can do if your program is well documented is well generate javadoc, it's the defenitions of classes, members and functions with comments, whitout the actual implementation.

Comment: Look into structural search and replace, you can probably pull it off with that one.

Comment: How about creating interfaces? Is there a function that copies the javadoc when you create a interface in IntelliJ?

Comment: Why the downvoting? isn't a legit question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such shortcut in IntelliJ IDEA (nor in any other IDE or source code editor that I'm aware of).

Answer (score 0):

Generate the Javadoc and then use this tool to recreate the code from Javadoc: http://codavaj.sourceforge.net/